# EV3 bluetooth controller for mac

Tags: ev3, remote-control

Is there a suitable EV3 controller for mac? It should be a compatible alternative from the official EV3 controller in the iOS app store or google play.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [MonoBrick Communication Library](http://www.monobrick.dk/software/monobrick/).  It is supported for Mac OS and does use Bluetooth as a way of communicating with the EV3 brick.

MonoBrick was [listed by IntroRobotics](http://www.intorobotics.com/additional-lego-ev3-resources-robotic-applications/) with three other software development resources for EV3.